# How can I use ffmpeg with youtube-dl?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I have this "setup", but it stopped working (I did not change anything in the code):

```
  private Process StartFfmpeg(string URL)
    {
        string args = $"/C youtube-dl --ignore-errors -o - {URL} | ffmpeg -err_detect ignore_err -i pipe:0 -ac 2 -f s16le -ar 48000 pipe:1";
        return Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "cmd.exe",
            Arguments = args,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
        });
    }
```

(I get the stream by using 
`Stream stream = StartFfmpeg(URL).StandardOutput.BaseStream;`)
It just freezes. It doesn't throw any error (in a try/catch block) and I have the latest version of ffmpeg & youtube-dl. I've tried using older versions with no success. 
How can I get it working again? (This is my first post, sorry if its very bad)

Comment: Can you get the formatted command line string and ensure that it works in a shell?

Comment: "URL" is any youtube video URL (Ex.: [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4mHPeMGTJM) ). It works in cmd.